# Download Azure java function programmatically

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I have a java app that given Azure credentials and an Azure function URL should be able to download the given function code. I searched for such an API in the java SDK provided by Azure but couldn't find any.
For example in AWS we have the `GetFunctionRequest` object that allows this behavior.

How can this be done? Is there a built-in API for Azure for that?

Answer (score 0):

> How can this be done? Is there a built-in API for Azure for that?

AFAIK, currently it is not available in azure. Because `AWS Lambda` has the event type defines the **schema of objects**. But in `Azure Function` it has **triggers and bindings**.

Layers are defined by **AWS Lambda** as a library distribution method, custom runtimes to support additional languages, and other dependencies.

The programming model for **AWS Lambda** is simple. A function takes a JSON object as input and can produce another JSON object. **The structure of those objects is specified by the event type, which is described and defined in language SDKs.**

The **Azure Functions** model is more complex, relying on **triggers and bindings**. The function listens for a trigger, which is an event. **To pull and/or push extra data during processing, the function can have any number of input and output bindings**.

Comment: Hey, did the suggestion work? do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot. [Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)